# Как автоматически сформировать переменные в массиве?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Имеется форма, количество полей, которые отправляются в php всегда разное, по этому все задается через переменные:

```
$conex=2 // номер выпадающего поля из ряда, всегда разный
$colnum=4; // количество полей

for ($i = 1; $i <= colnum; $i++) {if ($i==$conex)continue;
echo '<input type=text name=foo'.$i. '>'; // примерно такой инпут у формы

$foo1=$_post[foo1]; // 
// Все они таким же способом через for генерируются
```

Есть массив:

```
$arr = array("$id;$foo1;$foo3;$foo4); // условие на формирование фу такое же, как и у полей (for), то есть всегда есть то, что игнорируется

print_r($arr); // Должно быть примерно так: Array ( [0] => 88;Text 1; Текст 3; Текст 4 ) то есть текст 2 игнорируется
```

Вопрос: как сюда `$arr = array("$id; !место! );`

Вставить то, что у меня генерируется аналогичным способом, как for

Затем `$arr` будет загружаться в csv файл, тоесть на выходе мне необходимо иметь именно такой массив: `Array ( [0] => 88;Text 1;Текст 3;Текст 4).` 
Возможно в рамках моего вопроса решения нет и желаемое реализуется другим способом, в таком случае прошу накинуть идею и для этого.
P.S. Пишу с телефона.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$conex=2;
$colnum=4;
$foo=array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= colnum; $i++) {
    if ($i==$conex)continue;
    echo '<input type=text name=foo'.$i. '>';
    $foo[$i] = $_post["foo".$i];
}

$arr = array("$id;".implode(";", $foo));
```

Другой вопрос, зачем вам хранить в массиве всего одну строку.

Comment: Извините, это должно работать, если сам foo не задан? У меня как раз c этим проблема. С разделением знаком. С foo[$i] = $_post["foo".$i];
У меня проблем нет, в примере я написал информацию на выходе. Такую же мне необходимо организовать в массиве. Тоесть заставить например это
$arr = array("$id;". for ($i = 1; $i <= colnum; $i++) {
    if ($i==$conex)continue;
    echo ';'.$foo[$i];
})); Работать

Comment: @Dvashington если вы внимательно посмотрите на мой код, то увидите, что элемент массива $foo[$conex] не создается. Соответственно склейку он не попадет

Comment: Я думаю сработает. Вы разложили каждый элемент массива, а потом склеили. Я до этого не додумался. Хотя решение было очевидно.